# Ruby: How to write a "DRY"/dynamic/flexible tree-like loop structure

Tags: ruby, loops, dry

I am looking for the best way to accomplish the following structure/logic problem in Ruby:

A website needs to be crawled completely, collecting the title of every page.

But:

- The tree-like structure of the website is not known (how many "levels", "branches", etc.)
- The code should be "DRY" (= "Don't Repeat Yourself")

The following (simplified) example would of course be totally stupid:

```
url = some_root_url
@title_collection = Array.new

go_to_page(url)
@title_collection << find_all_titles_on_page
urls = find_all_urls_on_page

urls.each do |url|
    go_to_page(url)
    @title_collection << find_all_titles_on_page
    urls = find_all_urls_on_page

    urls.each do |url|
        go_to_page(url)
        @title_collection << find_all_titles_on_page
        urls = find_all_urls_on_page

        urls.each do |url|
            go_to_page(url)
            @title_collection << find_all_titles_on_page
            urls = find_all_urls_on_page

            urls.each do |url|
                go_to_page(url)
                @title_collection << find_all_titles_on_page
                urls = find_all_urls_on_page

                urls.each do |url|
                    go_to_page(url)
                    @title_collection << find_all_titles_on_page
                    urls = find_all_urls_on_page

                    [...]
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

So how would you accomplish that flexibly and efficiently, in a "DRY" way?

Thanks a lot!

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is your friend:

```
def walk_tree(url)
  go_to_page(url)
  title_collection << find_all_titles_on_page
  urls = find_all_urls_on_page

  urls.each do |child_url|
    title_collection << walk_tree(child_url)
  end

  title_collection
end
```

Comment: One more thing: If I'm not mistaken, the variable 'urls' would be re-initialized in each child loop, thereby deleting the 'urls' from its parent loop. In this case, there would have to be a mechanism which makes the 'urls' variable unique for each child loop, i.e. by including the number of the current level and of the current branch, like: urls_1_1, urls_1_2, urls_1_3 / urls_2_1, urls_2_2, urls_2_3 / etc, right?

Comment: urls is unique to the scope of walk_tree, aka it is reinitialized with each call.